# Get data from two collection with Rails 3.1 and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have two models called Post and User, Post belongs_to user and User has_many posts. When I list all posts I also want the user username and email to be included. I a relational database I would use join but how can I do this with Mongoid?

Comment: You should embedded your posts into each user or the user into each posts. Depends on which one you want to list. I would say embed the user into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is eager load your `User` model when querying for your posts. You can do this using the [`includes` method](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#includes).

Using your example above, you could do something like:

```
Post.includes(:user).all
```